# How to wrap text in a column in Latex?

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|X|X|X|X|@{}}
        \hline
        Network & Feature Maps & Dense Layer & Epochs\\
        \hline \hline
        VGG16C++ & 3x3: 64/64/128/128/256/256/256/512/512/512/512/512/512 & 4096/4096/1000 & 30\\
        VGG19C++ & 3x3: 64/64/128/128/256/256/256/256/512/512/512/512/512/512/512/512 & 4096/4096/1000 & 30\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx} 

\end{table}
```

The text in the second column goes out of the column.How can I correct this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: Simply replace the slash symbols (`/`) with `\slash`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Oops sorry ! I'll keep that thing in mind next time.Thanks for your tip

Comment: @Adit - Please see the answer I just posted for some additional ideas regarding your table.

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are not allowed after a "hard-coded" slash symbol, `/`. To fix this, simply replace all `/` symbols (especially those in the second column) with `\slash` (a "soft-coded" slash symbol).

Some additional thoughts:

- For columns 1, 3, and 4, using the basic `l` column type would seem preferable to using the `X` column type. For sure, no line wrapping is needed (or even desirable) in these columns.
- The `\centering` directive is pointless since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`.
- Please consider giving the table a much more "open" look, by omitting all vertical lines and by using the well-spaced horizontal lines of the `booktabs` package. The effect of making this change is illustrated in the second table below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional -- for a "less-cramped look"
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l| >{\RaggedRight}X |l|l|}
        \hline
        Network & Feature Maps & Dense Layer & Epochs\\
        \hline \hline
        VGG16C++ & 3$\times$3: 64\slash64\slash128\slash128\slash256\slash256\slash256\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512 
        & 4096/4096/1000 & 30\\
        VGG19C++ & 3$\times$3: 64\slash64\slash128\slash128\slash256\slash256\slash256\slash256\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512 
        & 4096/4096/1000 & 30\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \bigskip\bigskip

    \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt} % reset to default
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l >{\RaggedRight}X ll@{}}
        \toprule
        Network & Feature Maps & Dense Layer & Epochs\\
        \midrule
        VGG16C++ & 3$\times$3: 64\slash64\slash128\slash128\slash256\slash256\slash256\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512 
        & 4096/4096/1000 & 30\\ \addlinespace
        VGG19C++ & 3$\times$3: 64\slash64\slash128\slash128\slash256\slash256\slash256\slash256\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512\slash512 
        & 4096/4096/1000 & 30\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```